# Google OAuth: Only revoke authorization to selected scopes (not all)

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google OAuth to access users' Google Sheets and Drive. However, I want to give users an option to revoke the access but if a user decides to keep Google Sheets and revoke Drive, they will unintentionally revoke all the access.

How to allow "decremental authorization" so the users can remove certain scopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to [revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke) a single scope.  When a user revokes your access it will be to all scopes that they have granted you.